# Understanding SSL - Steal public key during browser-server handshake

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate

In ssl protocol, during handshake, server will send certificate with its corresponding public key. What if attacker during handshake,steals public key. Can attacker then steal each response from server and decrypt it with ssl public key and steal information?

I am new into this so maybe question is stupid, but this is first thing that I have in my mind now when I read a little bit about SSL online :)

Comment: public key is used for encryption, private key is used for decryption

Comment: but I read it something like that public key can decrypt something that is encrypted with private key and opposite. @sinanspd

Comment: Well TLS does have asymmetric encryption but it also establishes a new session key every time. After the handshake the public keys aren't used for the rest of the communication.

Comment: you read something that is wrong. Back in 1978 people were misled by the similarity between encrypting and signing for one algorithm only (RSA) into saying that signing is 'encrypting with the private key'. In fact systems using this directly were broken, and since about 1990 no competent design does it, but infinite websites contime to repeat the error. Also this is not a programming or development issue; on security.SX and crypto.SX, where it is ontopic, it has been addressed repeatedly, see my partial list at https://security.stackexchange.com/a/159289